# How to create a box in Powershell using Box Characters

Tags: powershell

I was wondering how I would go about creating a box to go around a text menu in PowerShell.

I am supposed to be box characters to do this and put the values of these characters into an array.

$BoxCharacters = "═", "╔", "╗", "╚", "╝", "║"

But how do I go about multiplying them for the number I need for the menu I am surrounding. For example, $Var.length equals 6, I want to multiply this.

I would also like to know how to multiply this number to add spaces, like $Var.length * " " which would insert, say 6 spaces if the length was 6 again here. But this is wrong, so how do I go about these things.

Any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your menu is a block of text surrounded by carriage return, new line (`` `r`n ``), the following code will write a box around the block of text:

```
$HorizontalBoxChar = [string][char]9552
$VerticalBoxChar = [string][char]9553
$TopLeftBoxChar = [string][char]9556
$TopRightBoxChar = [string][char]9559
$BottomLeftBoxChar = [string][char]9562
$BottomRightBoxChar = [string][char]9565

Function CreateBoxText() {
    Begin {
        $lines = @()
    }
    Process {
        $maxLength = 0
        $lineCount = 0
        $_ -split "`r`n" | ForEach-Object {
            $lines += $_
            If ($lines[$lineCount].Length -gt $maxLength) {
                $maxLength = $lines[$lineCount].Length
            }
            $lineCount++
        }
    }
    End {
        $TopLeftBoxChar + ($HorizontalBoxChar * ($maxLength + 2)) + $TopRightBoxChar
        For ($i = 0; $i -lt $lineCount; $i++) {
            $VerticalBoxChar + " " + $lines[$i] + (" " * ($maxLength - $lines[$i].Length + 1)) + $VerticalBoxChar
        }
        $BottomLeftBoxChar + ($HorizontalBoxChar * ($maxLength + 2)) + $BottomRightBoxChar
    }   
}

"List Item 1`r`nList Item 2222`r`nThe Final List Item" | CreateBoxText
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer something similar, but a bit more versatile since you can add a title to the menu. And it will number your entries for you, and give you a little better buffer around things I think.

```
Function MenuMaker{
    param(
        [string]$Title = $null,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        ValueFromPipeline = $true)][String[]]$Selections
        )

    $Width = if($Title){$Length = $Title.Length;$Length2 = $Selections|%{$_.length}|Sort -Descending|Select -First 1;$Length2,$Length|Sort -Descending|Select -First 1}else{$Selections|%{$_.length}|Sort -Descending|Select -First 1}
    $Buffer = if(($Width*1.5) -gt 78){(78-$width)/2}else{$width/4}
    if($Buffer -gt 6){$Buffer = 6}
    $MaxWidth = $Buffer*2+$Width+$($Selections.count).length
    $Menu = @()
    $Menu += "╔"+"═"*$maxwidth+"╗"
    if($Title){
        $Menu += "║"+" "*[Math]::Floor(($maxwidth-$title.Length)/2)+$Title+" "*[Math]::Ceiling(($maxwidth-$title.Length)/2)+"║"
        $Menu += "╟"+"─"*$maxwidth+"╢"
    }
    For($i=1;$i -le $Selections.count;$i++){
        $Item = "$i`. "
        $Menu += "║"+" "*$Buffer+$Item+$Selections[$i-1]+" "*($MaxWidth-$Buffer-$Item.Length-$Selections[$i-1].Length)+"║"
    }
    $Menu += "╚"+"═"*$maxwidth+"╝"
    $menu
}
```

So, given the input of `MenuMaker -Title "Test Menu" -Selections @("Dog","Horse","Squirrel")` it outputs:

```
╔══════════════╗
║  Test Menu   ║
╟──────────────╢
║  1. Dog      ║
║  2. Horse    ║
║  3. Squirrel ║
╚══════════════╝
```